# SetState doesn't update when button is clicked

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, model-view-controller, state, setstate

I'm trying to change the color at the button click using `setState`. But it doesn't change the state when the button is clicked. I have attached my `App.js` and `Index.html` files.

It works when I try it on Visual studio code. but it doesn't work in visual studio 2019 with asp.net mvc. I want to try it with Asp.net mvc with reactjs intergrated project

```js
class Business extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {color: "red" };
    }
 
    changeColor = () => {
        this.setState({ color: "blue" });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>My Favorite Color is {this.state.color}</h1>
                <button type="button" onClick={this.changeColor}>Change Color</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

```html
@using React.Web.Mvc

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@Html.React("Business", new
    {
      


    })
```

Comment: your code is working fine in stakblitz, check the link ``https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ebfpee``

Comment: Your react code is absolutely fine. It is working correctly for me.

Comment: It works when I try it on Visual studio code. but it doesn't work in visual studio 2019 with asp.net mvc. I want to try it with Asp.net mvc with reactjs intergrated project.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your code with as below:

```js
class Business extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        color: "red"
      };
  }
 
  changeColor = () => {
      /*Please remove alert*/
      alert('Working');
      this.setState({ color: "blue" });
  }
  render() {
      return (
          <div>
              <h1>
                My Favorite Color is {this.state.color}
              </h1>
              <button type="button" onClick={this.changeColor}>Change Color</button>
          </div>
      );
  }
}
export default Business;
```